# Are chicken gizzards okay to eat if still pink inside?

Tags: chicken

I sautéed chicken gizzards for quite a while, then added water and boiled another 15 minutes but they are still pink inside. Are they safe to eat even though they are pink inside?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After boiling for that period of time (especially after sauteing), the gizzards have certainly reached a "safe" temperature. They are probably not really good eating though. Gizzards are a tough piece of meat. They benefit from a low and slow cooking process. Here's a pretty good article from [Livestrong](http://www.livestrong.com/article/428970-ways-to-cook-chicken-gizzards/). Among other advice, they suggest braising (or boiling) **first** for 15 or so minutes, **then** searing at a very high heat.

Here's a pretty typical recipe for [Southern Fried Chicken Gizzards](http://www.justapinch.com/recipes/main-course/chicken/pams-tender-fried-chicken-gizzards.html). It starts with simmering the gizzards for 45 minutes or longer, **then** cooling, **then** breading.

Safety really isn't the issue here, or color; after 15 minutes of boiling, you have well surpassed the USDA recommended temperature of 165F (74C). For good flavor though, they need more time.

> Traditionally, chicken or turkey giblets are cooked by simmering in water
>   for use in flavoring soups, gravies or poultry stuffing. Once cooked, the
>   liver will become crumbly and the heart and gizzard will soften and
>   become easy to chop. Cooked giblets should have a firm texture.
>   Casseroles containing giblets should be cooked to 165 °F. Stuffing should
>   also be cooked to 165 °F. Chicken giblets are commonly fried or broiled.
>   Leftovers should be refrigerated within 2 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I cook chicken gizzards and hearts at least once a week. I sautee them in butter, garlic and white wine for about 15 minutes. They are still pink in the middle when I eat them and perfectly safe and tender.

Comment: Welcome to SA, Nicole!  You're posting an answer on a question that is 6 years old and already has a pretty good answer.  You might try focusing on questions that do not have an answer instead.